# How to get float value in ResultSet of Hibernate Query?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, grails

I have the following query

```
select sum(r.score)/count(r) from Rating as r
    group by r.item
    order by sum(r.score)/count(r) desc
```

My problem is that hibernate rounds the result sum(r.score)/count(r).

How can I force Hibernate to return the float value of the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only bother about finding an average then you can use [avg()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e2900) aggregate function which always returns a `Double`.

```
select avg(r.score) from Rating as r
    group by r.item
    order by avg(r.score) desc
```

Comment: What to du in other cases if I need float?

Comment: You can use CAST as float for the whole result if you need. `CAST(sum(r.score)/count(r) as float)` @confile. I agree with Nathan as well.

Answer (score 1):

`avg` is best for this situation. For the general case where you want to convert to double you can use CAST:

```
select sum(r.score) / (CAST (count(r) AS DOUBLE PRECISION)) from Rating as r
    group by r.item
    order by sum(r.score) / (CAST (count(r) AS DOUBLE PRECISION)) desc
```